# Youtube analytics example: Keep google account signed in

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-api, youtube-api

I'm working with this Oauth2 example from Youtube API's documentation: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript?hl=es-419

The problem is: every time I execute a request it asks me for sign in with a google account.

The question is: how can I keep the user signed in? With long access token or something like that.

I'm working with a laravel app.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement [OAuth 2.0 Authorization](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication).

> The YouTube Data API supports the [OAuth 2.0 protocol](http://oauth.net/2/) for
>   authorizing access to private user data. The list below explains some
>   core OAuth 2.0 concepts:

Here are some important points from YouTube API.

> - When a user first attempts to use functionality in your application that requires the user to be logged in to a Google Account or YouTube
>     account, your application initiates the OAuth 2.0 authorization
>     process.
> - Your application directs the user to Google's authorization server. The link to that page specifies the scope of access that your
>     application is requesting for the user's account. The scope specifies
>     the resources that your application can retrieve, insert, update, or
>     delete when acting as the authenticated user.
> - If the user consents to authorize your application to access those resources, Google returns a token to your application. Depending on
>     your application's type, it either validates the token or exchanges it
>     for a different type of token.
>
> For example, a server-side web application exchanges the returned
>   token for an access token and a refresh token. The access token lets
>   the application authorize requests on the user's behalf, and the
>   refresh token lets the application retrieve a new access token when
>   the original access token expires.
>
> *Note: Important: You need to [obtain authorization credentials in the Google Developers Console](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application) to be able to use OAuth 2.0
>   authorization.*

Follow the steps in this documentation to [obtain authorization credentials](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application).

> Your application must have authorization credentials to be able to use
>   the YouTube Data API. This document describes the different types of
>   authorization credentials that the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/)
>   supports. It also explains how to find or create authorization
>   credentials for your project.